# Adding ListItems causes an error "Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, listitem, dropdownbox

I am getting an error message "Cannot have multiple items selected in a DropDownList."  After searching SO and google, I have narrowed the error cause to the ddlVendor.Items.Add(li) code block :

```
ListItem li = new ListItem();
string[] TransDetail = Trans[0].Split(',');

li.Text = TransDetail[0].ToString() + ", " + TransDetail[1].ToString();

//TransDetail[2] = VendorId;
//TransDetail[3] = TransId;
li.Value = TransDetail[2].ToString() + ", " + TransDetail[3].ToString();
//ddlVendor.Items.Add(li);
```

I have tried `ClearSelection()` and `.SelectedItem` but no luck.

Any ideas why the code block above would be causing an error?

**Update**: When I comment `ddlVendor.Items.Add(li);` the page loads fine.
Is there another way to add an item to a dropdownlist box? I am using VS 2008.

Comment: Is it having some sort of problem having a comma-separated list as the value?

Comment: Do you have multiple ddl's bound to the same datasource?

Comment: @Kevin, no multiple ddl datasource binding.

Comment: @GarrisonNeely... interesting. I will check it out tomorrow and let you know. Very interesting observation

Comment: @GarrisonNeely... unfortunately that does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved by changing the code to add items to the dropdown list ([Add value manually into DropDownList, CheckBoxList and RadioButtonList.](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/aspnet/threads/87886/add-value-manually-into-dropdownlist-checkboxlist-and-radiobuttonlist)):

```
YourDropDownList.Items.Add(new ListItem("JAKARTA", "JKT"));
```